# Getting rid of a big switch case

Tags: c#, oop, object, switch-statement, polymorphism

So I have been looking around and it seems like the correct answer to getting rid of big switch case is polymorphism, but I just can't figure out how I can change this from conditionnal to poplymorphic. Is this the right solution here?

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Menu");
            Console.WriteLine(@"1.Create Account");
            Console.WriteLine(@"2.ATM");
            Console.WriteLine(@"3.Account info");
            Console.Write(@"Please enter your selection: ");
            var menuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            switch (menuChoice)
            {
                case 1:                       
                    atm.CreateAccount();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Console.WriteLine(@"1.Deposit Or Withdraw");
                    Console.WriteLine(@"1.Deposit");
                    Console.WriteLine(@"2.Withdraw");
                    Console.Write(@"Please enter your selection: ");
                    var atmMenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    switch (atmMenuChoice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            atm.Deposit();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            atm.Withdraw();
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine(@"Invalid selection!");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    atm.AccountInfo();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(@"Invalid selection!");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Polymorphism could be an answer, but so could a simple refactor.

Comment: Looks like a great candidate for a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Would also make your interface easily extensible.

Comment: I would think that the logic is all right. The only thing i would change is to put all the logic in case 2: to another method to keep code clean

Comment: The only pattern I know of here for polymorphism is the strategy pattern, but I don't think it applies here... to simple for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this I tend to use a `Dictionary<string, Action>` to lookup what to do for each input.

Something like:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
  { "1", atm.CreateAccount }
  { "2", AtmSelection } //This would do the same as below with the atmActions dictionary
  { "3", atm.AccountInfo }
}

var atmActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
  { "1", atm.Deposit }
  { "2", atm.Withdraw }
}

var input = GetInput(); //From stdin as you do currently

if (actions.TryGetValue(input, out var action)) 
{
    action();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection");
}
```

I personally find this easier to read than a massive nested switch statement

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  Now each `Action` in the dictionary can be unit tested individually and this reduces Cyclomatic Complexity of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The preference for polymorphism over a switch usually applies when you're using some sort of serialization framework. Imagine that your `int` is the serialized representation of a member of a class of singletons, all of which have a particular method that operates on (or [visits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)) your `atm` object. Then you could deserialize the instance and call that method:

```
var foo = deserializer.deserialize(intVal);
foo.doStuff(atm);
```

There's still a switch involved, but it's inside the serialization framework and you don't have to maintain it.  If you want to implement a similar pattern without a serialization framework, you'll have to write the switch yourself. The benefit is that you can separate the switch from the rest of the logic:

```
Foo GetFoo(int type) {
    // switch on type 
}
var foo = GetFoo(intVal);
foo.doStuff(atm);
```

This pattern developed in languages that do not (or did not) have function pointers or the equivalent. In languages that do have function pointers, a map of `int` values to functions as suggested in another answer would essentially accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I may have gone a little crazy here, but this works in a similar way to Scott's answer.

```
static IEnumerable<MenuItem> RootMenu;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  RootMenu = BuildRootMenu();
  MenuItem.DisplayMenu(RootMenu, new Atm());
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates the entire menu
/// </summary>
static IEnumerable<MenuItem> BuildRootMenu()
{
  MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem() { DisplayText = "Create Account", AtmAction = (a) => a.CreateAccount() };

  MenuItem item2_1 = new MenuItem() { DisplayText = "Deposit", AtmAction = (a) => a.Deposit() };
  MenuItem item2_2 = new MenuItem() { DisplayText = "Withdraw", AtmAction = (a) => a.Withdraw() };
  MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem() { DisplayText = "ATM", AtmAction = (a) => MenuItem.DisplayMenu(new List<MenuItem> { item2_1, item2_2 }, a) };

  MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem() { DisplayText = "Account Info", AtmAction = (a) => a.CreateAccount() };

  return new List<MenuItem> { item1, item2, item3 };
}

class MenuItem
{
  public String DisplayText;
  public Action<Atm> AtmAction = null;

  public void Execute(Atm atm)
  {
    AtmAction(atm);
    DisplayMenu(RootMenu, atm);
  }

  public static void DisplayMenu(IEnumerable<MenuItem> menuItems, Atm atm)
  {
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var mi in menuItems)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + mi.DisplayText);
      i++;
    }

    var rk = Console.ReadKey();
    menuItems.ToArray()[int.Parse(rk.KeyChar.ToString()) - 1].Execute(atm);
  }
}


class Atm
{
  public void Deposit()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ran Deposit");
  }
  public void Withdraw()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ran Withdraw");
  }
  public void CreateAccount()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ran CreateAccount");
  }
  public void AccountInfo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ran AccountInfo");
  }
```